# How do i stop Entity Framework converting Json UTC datetime when i want to store UTC datetime

Tags: json, vb.net, entity-framework, datetime, utc

Banging my head against the wall on this issue.

I receive a text string to my web service which is generated with json, for example:

```
"2014-09-19T17:00:00.000Z"
```

When i assign this to my database in entity framework, it changes it to 20:00 instead of 17:00.  So i specify that it is UTC date by

```
DateTime.SpecifyKind("2014-09-19T17:00:00.000Z", DateTimeKind.UTC)
```

But this returns 20:00 as well!  I could fix this by removing the Z but that is a dirty workaround as could be receiving time zones instead of Z.  Is there way of setting telling vb to ignore the timezone and just save it as 17:00?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [here](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/04/08/entity-framework-and-datetime-of-unspecified-kind/) EF will always read the date time value as if it was of Unspecified kind since DateTime does not store time zone. Consider using DateTimeOffset which does store time zone.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Pawel for the hint.  To help anyone else with this problem, please see the code below:

```
New DateTimeOffset("2014-09-19T17:00:00.000Z").ToUniversalTime
```